# Optimize two variable function with O(log n) time

Tags: algorithm

Given integer variable x, ranging from 0 to n. We have two functions f(x) and g(x) with the following properties:

- f(x) is a strictly increasing function; with x1 > x2, we have f(x1) > f(x2)
- g(x) is a strictly decreasing function; with x1 > x2, we have g(x1) < g(x2)
- f(x) and g(x) are black-box functions, and have constant time complexity O(1)

The problem is to solve an optimization problem and determine optimal x:

minimize f(x) + g(x)

An easy approach is a simple linear scan to test all x from 0 to n with time complexity of O(n). I am curious if there is an approach to solve it with O(log n).

Comment: I thought of binary search, but it seems not to work.

Comment: To be clear, are we allowed to evaluate f and g each in O(1) time, or just f + g?

Comment: The first one, we are alllowed to evaluate f with O(1) and g with O(1).

Comment: Are the functions continuous?

Comment: We don't know, they are black-box functions. We don't know f(x) and g(x)'s values until we evaluate them.

Comment: Are they on the domain R?

Comment: No, Integer only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such solution.

Start with `f(i) = 2i`.  And `g(i) = 2n - 2i`.  These meet your requirements, and the minimum is going to be `2n`.

Now at one point `k` replace `g(k)` with `2n - 2k - 1`.  This still meets your requirements, the minimum is now going to be `2n-1`, and you only can get this knowledge from asking about the `k`th.  No amount of other questions give you any information that is different than the original one.  So there is no way around asking `n` questions to notice a difference between the modified and original functions.

Comment: Assuming O(log n) is not working, do you mean we cannot even do better than O(n)?

Comment: Yes, integer only

Comment: @user16830227 this means that you must look at every `x`, because if you skip one value `x=k`, you could miss a decisive point (as explained here). So O(n).

Comment: Thank you bros, great proof by contradiction with a nice example.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the problem in such general shape has an answer.

Let `f(x)=2x` for even `x` and `2x+1` for odd,
and `g(x)=-2x-1`.
Then `f+g` oscillates between 0 and 1 for integer arguments and every odd `x` is a local minimum.

And, similarly to example by @btilly, a small variation in the `g(x)` definition may introduce a global minimum anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your example rejects my intention. :) As @btilly answers the question first, so I mark his solution as the one. However, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I already marked one response as the solution. With certain special cases, you have to brutal force all x to get the optimal value. However, my real intention is see if there is any early stopping criteria when we observe a specific pattern. An example early stopping solution is as follows.

First we solve the boundary conditions at 0 and n, we have f(0), f(n), and g(0), g(n), with any x, we have:

f(0) < f(x) < f(n)

g(0) > g(x) > g(n)

Given two trials x and y, y > x, if we observe:

f(y) + g(y) > f(x) + g(x) // x solution is better

f(y) - f(x) > g(y) - g(n) // no more room to improve after y

Then, there is no need to test solutions after y.